# PHP/MySQL - an array filter for bots

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

I'm making a hit counter. I have a database and I store the IP and `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` of the visitors. Now I need to add a filter, so I can put away the hits, that are made by bots. I found out, that many bots usually keep some common words in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` , so I's like to make and array of words, that would keep the bot from displaying in the results.

Here is what I have now:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($yesterday, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

<-- Here I need a code, that would run through an array and check, 
if it containts the keywords and if it doesn't ... just count++; -->

```
    }
```

Also if you know any other way of detecting and removing the bots from the results, I'd be verry thankful. Cheers

Comment: Another way to do it is filter the results with SQL so you don't have to do any filtering in your code. You'd need to test the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array of words with `foreach` and check if the current word exists in the UA string using [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos):

```
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strpos($row['user_agent'], $word) !== FALSE) {
        // word exists in string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Dimitar Christoff's list ended up with this script:

```
function isBot($user_agent){
    $bots = array('bingbot', 'msn', 'abacho', 'abcdatos', 'abcsearch', 'acoon', 'adsarobot', 'aesop', 'ah-ha',
            'alkalinebot', 'almaden', 'altavista', 'antibot', 'anzwerscrawl', 'aol', 'search', 'appie', 'arachnoidea',
            'araneo', 'architext', 'ariadne', 'arianna', 'ask', 'jeeves', 'aspseek', 'asterias', 'astraspider', 'atomz',
            'augurfind', 'backrub', 'baiduspider', 'bannana_bot', 'bbot', 'bdcindexer', 'blindekuh', 'boitho', 'boito',
            'borg-bot', 'bsdseek', 'christcrawler', 'computer_and_automation_research_institute_crawler', 'coolbot',
            'cosmos', 'crawler', 'crawler@fast', 'crawlerboy', 'cruiser', 'cusco', 'cyveillance', 'deepindex', 'denmex',
            'dittospyder', 'docomo', 'dogpile', 'dtsearch', 'elfinbot', 'entire', 'web', 'esismartspider', 'exalead',
            'excite', 'ezresult', 'fast', 'fast-webcrawler', 'fdse', 'felix', 'fido', 'findwhat', 'finnish', 'firefly',
            'firstgov', 'fluffy', 'freecrawl', 'frooglebot', 'galaxy', 'gaisbot', 'geckobot', 'gencrawler', 'geobot',
            'gigabot', 'girafa', 'goclick', 'goliat', 'googlebot', 'griffon', 'gromit', 'grub-client', 'gulliver',
            'gulper', 'henrythemiragorobot', 'hometown', 'hotbot', 'htdig', 'hubater', 'ia_archiver', 'ibm_planetwide',
            'iitrovatore-setaccio', 'incywincy', 'incrawler', 'indy', 'infonavirobot', 'infoseek', 'ingrid', 'inspectorwww',
            'intelliseek', 'internetseer', 'ip3000.com-crawler', 'iron33', 'jcrawler', 'jeeves', 'jubii', 'kanoodle',
            'kapito', 'kit_fireball', 'kit-fireball', 'ko_yappo_robot', 'kototoi', 'lachesis', 'larbin', 'legs',
            'linkwalker', 'lnspiderguy', 'look.com', 'lycos', 'mantraagent', 'markwatch', 'maxbot', 'mercator', 'merzscope',
            'meshexplorer', 'metacrawler', 'mirago', 'mnogosearch', 'moget', 'motor', 'muscatferret', 'nameprotect',
            'nationaldirectory', 'naverrobot', 'nazilla', 'ncsa', 'beta', 'netnose', 'netresearchserver', 'ng/1.0',
            'northerlights', 'npbot', 'nttdirectory_robot', 'nutchorg', 'nzexplorer', 'odp', 'openbot', 'openfind',
            'osis-project', 'overture', 'perlcrawler', 'phpdig', 'pjspide', 'polybot', 'pompos', 'poppi', 'portalb',
            'psbot', 'quepasacreep', 'rabot', 'raven', 'rhcs', 'robi', 'robocrawl', 'robozilla', 'roverbot', 'scooter',
            'scrubby', 'search.ch', 'search.com.ua', 'searchfeed', 'searchspider', 'searchuk', 'seventwentyfour',
            'sidewinder', 'sightquestbot', 'skymob', 'sleek', 'slider_search', 'slurp', 'solbot', 'speedfind', 'speedy',
            'spida', 'spider_monkey', 'spiderku', 'stackrambler', 'steeler', 'suchbot', 'suchknecht.at-robot', 'suntek',
            'szukacz', 'surferf3', 'surfnomore', 'surveybot', 'suzuran', 'synobot', 'tarantula', 'teomaagent', 'teradex',
            't-h-u-n-d-e-r-s-t-o-n-e', 'tigersuche', 'topiclink', 'toutatis', 'tracerlock', 'turnitinbot', 'tutorgig',
            'uaportal', 'uasearch.kiev.ua', 'uksearcher', 'ultraseek', 'unitek', 'vagabondo', 'verygoodsearch', 'vivisimo',
            'voilabot', 'voyager', 'vscooter', 'w3index', 'w3c_validator', 'wapspider', 'wdg_validator', 'webcrawler',
            'webmasterresourcesdirectory', 'webmoose', 'websearchbench', 'webspinne', 'whatuseek', 'whizbanglab', 'winona',
            'wire', 'wotbox', 'wscbot', 'www.webwombat.com.au', 'xenu', 'link', 'sleuth', 'xyro', 'yahoobot', 'yahoo!',
            'slurp', 'yandex', 'yellopet-spider', 'zao/0', 'zealbot', 'zippy', 'zyborg', 'mediapartners-google'
                );
    $user_agent = strtolower($user_agent);
    foreach($bots as $bot){
        if(strpos($user_agent, $bot) === true){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: who made this awful list? one of the most popular bot isn't here: mediapartners-google, aka adsense and others too

Comment: @yes123, thanks for noticing. You are very welcome to suggest more bots, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Short common strings like `'aol', 'web', 'link', 'msn', 'beta', 'motor'` is probably not safe for filtering bots. Words that on the other hand are safe to filter by is `'bot', 'spider', 'crawl'` which makes at least half the entries in the list unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

And why not?

```
$bots=array('google', 'bing', 'yahoo', 'bot', 'crawler', 'baiduspider');
if(!preg_match('/('.join('|', $bots).')/is', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
  //record to db code
}
```

Comment: `google, bing, yahoo` is unnecessary in the list because they will be targeted by `bot`. I would recommend changing `crawler` to `crawl` and `baiduspider` to `spider` as well.

Answer (score 0):

there are certain systems that try and support semi-current DB of known bot strings, such as CubeCart and oscommerce before. they do that in order to have a boolean function that filters a user from bot in real time through string comparison of the user agent string against a file called spiders.txt. after discovering a bot, they disable shopping basket and login functionality etc.

here is the latest spiders.txt contents:

abacho
abcdatos
abcsearch
acoon
adsarobot
aesop
ah-ha
alkalinebot
almaden
altavista
antibot
anzwerscrawl
aol search
appie
arachnoidea
araneo
architext
ariadne
arianna
ask jeeves
aspseek
asterias
astraspider
atomz
augurfind
backrub
baiduspider
bannana_bot
bbot
bdcindexer
blindekuh
boitho
boito
borg-bot
bsdseek
christcrawler
computer_and_automation_research_institute_crawler
coolbot
cosmos
crawler
crawler@fast
crawlerboy
cruiser
cusco
cyveillance
deepindex
denmex
dittospyder
docomo
dogpile
dtsearch
elfinbot
entire web
esismartspider
exalead
excite
ezresult
fast
fast-webcrawler 
fdse
felix
fido
findwhat
finnish
firefly
firstgov
fluffy
freecrawl
frooglebot
galaxy
gaisbot
geckobot
gencrawler
geobot
gigabot
girafa
goclick
goliat
googlebot
griffon
gromit
grub-client
gulliver
gulper
henrythemiragorobot
hometown
hotbot
htdig
hubater
ia_archiver
ibm_planetwide
iitrovatore-setaccio
incywincy
incrawler
indy
infonavirobot
infoseek
ingrid
inspectorwww
intelliseek
internetseer
ip3000.com-crawler
iron33
jcrawler
jeeves
jubii
kanoodle
kapito
kit_fireball
kit-fireball
ko_yappo_robot
kototoi
lachesis
larbin
legs
linkwalker
lnspiderguy
look.com
lycos
mantraagent
markwatch
maxbot
mercator
merzscope
meshexplorer
metacrawler
mirago
mnogosearch
moget
motor
muscatferret
nameprotect
nationaldirectory
naverrobot
nazilla
ncsa beta
netnose
netresearchserver
ng/1.0
northerlights
npbot
nttdirectory_robot
nutchorg
nzexplorer
odp
openbot
openfind
osis-project
overture
perlcrawler
phpdig
pjspide
polybot
pompos
poppi
portalb
psbot
quepasacreep
rabot
raven
rhcs
robi
robocrawl
robozilla
roverbot
scooter
scrubby
search.ch
search.com.ua
searchfeed
searchspider
searchuk
seventwentyfour
sidewinder
sightquestbot
skymob
sleek
slider_search
slurp
solbot
speedfind
speedy
spida
spider_monkey
spiderku
stackrambler
steeler
suchbot
suchknecht.at-robot
suntek
szukacz
surferf3
surfnomore
surveybot
suzuran
synobot
tarantula
teomaagent
teradex
t-h-u-n-d-e-r-s-t-o-n-e
tigersuche
topiclink
toutatis
tracerlock
turnitinbot
tutorgig
uaportal
uasearch.kiev.ua
uksearcher
ultraseek
unitek
vagabondo
verygoodsearch
vivisimo
voilabot
voyager
vscooter
w3index
w3c_validator
wapspider
wdg_validator
webcrawler
webmasterresourcesdirectory
webmoose
websearchbench
webspinne
whatuseek
whizbanglab
winona
wire
wotbox
wscbot
www.webwombat.com.au
xenu link sleuth
xyro
yahoobot
yahoo! slurp
yandex
yellopet-spider
zao/0
zealbot
zippy
zyborg

as long as you don't do cloaking like [this](http://fragged.org/cubecart-problems-no-shopping-bakset-and-login-functionality-for-some-users_782.html), you're ok.