# CodeIgniter: index() begin called 3 times?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've encountered a weird problem. It seems that some of my controllers' index() methods are being executed 3 times when it should only be doing it once. The reason I found this out is because I am logging the number of times the index() method is executed -- and noticed records being inserted in 3s.

At this point, I am at a complete lost. I am unable to describe the problem any further as it is just very odd to me. Any ideas what might be happening?

**UPDATE:** It seems that the problem only exist when I have JavaScript turned on. When I turned of JavaScript, I no longer get the multiple entries. The problem controllers do have JavaScript. The JS is just some FB plugin and Google AdSense stuff.

Comment: can you present code of weird controller ?

Comment: Wait a sec, let me take my crystal ball and see what your code looks like....

Comment: As @bensiu said and ALSO provide the code from where that controller is being called!

Comment: @bensui: There are no loops in the index() method, if that is what you are wondering. As a matter of fact, I even commented out all the code except the part that does the logging during my debugging.

Comment: @Briedis: there is no need to be sarcastic.

Comment: @ifaour: controller is being called from the browser.

Comment: @StackOverlowNewbie: Still, without the code of the view I doubt one can help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had this kind of problem, the delay between requests was about 2-5 seconds. The cause was google adsense. It somehow makes another request from it's own server for no reason to the same page. To verify it, just store every requests IP and the user agent, if IP's (user agents too) are different, then you know the cause.

Solution? Give the user some kind of a token before visiting next page - if the token doesn't match on the next request - it's not the same user. Something like a XSRF protection :)

Comment: @Breidis: can you elaborate? Whatever token I give to the "user", googlebot will get the same thing (since it too is a "user", right?). Meaning, I still wouldn't be able to discriminate between a human user and googlebot.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the problem? You can't avoid that some crawlers will visit your site, that's just the way it is. Other problem (which I had) was that when a user submits some data that are later inserted in db - they became double-posted. One solution - add a captcha, I doubt the google bot will guess it :). The second solution - a token - would work if the submitting process is more than one step long. First step - save a token in the session and pass the same in a form's field. If at the last step before inserting in db they don't match - the request is from other source.

Comment: There is no form submission. I'm logging page views. The site I am working on allow sellers to advertise their products. Each product gets its own page -- and the sellers are charged based on how many users view their product page. We shouldn't charge the sellers when bots are viewing the page; we should only charge the sellers when an actual human user is viewing the product page. The problem seems that Google AdSense makes an additional 2 requests for the page the user is viewing, which inflates the page view count.

Comment: You can try filtering "invalid" users by their user agents. All crawlers mostly have special user agent names. Here is a topic on how to identify a bot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101165/php-mysql-an-array-filter-for-bots  You definetly shouldn't block bots entirely, you just should not log them :)