# How to prevent crawlers from following links?

Tags: html, seo, bots, googlebot

I'm building a site that will allow sellers to:

- list their products on my site
- have each product link back to the seller's site
- be charged for each link clicked

What I need to do now is to somehow make sure that I am only logging actual human users following the links to the sellers site. If it's a bot crawling the site, I shouldn't be charging the sellers for that.

Is there a way for me tell bots not to follow a certain link? I don't think it's `nofollow` as that is not intended to block access to content.

Comment: No. Any bot. I don't want to artificially increase the count of links clicked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to tell a bot not to follow a link is precisely to add rel=nofollow to your <a> tag.
Assuming you are also logging locally before forwarding to the external url you could also check the user agent string.

In fact, if you are going to ask people to pay based on number of referrals it might be an idea to log IP address and user agent  against each paid for click in case your stats are ever questioned.

Comment: I'm logging IP address. Good idea on User Agent.

Comment: The accepted answer is not correct. `rel="nofollow"` does not indicate to a general crawler that a URI should definitely not be followed. According to the spec (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-nofollow) it only indicates "that the link is not endorsed by the original author or publisher of the page, or that the link to the referenced document was included primarily because of a commercial relationship between people affiliated with the two pages."

Answer (score 3):

You just add a [**robots.txt**] file, e.g. like [this one](http://www.google.com/robots.txt).

You can find more info about [robots.txt] files on the net, e.g. [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcards in robots.txt?

Comment: The Google robots.txt file linked to above illustrates you can use wildcards for user agent. But since robots.txt is mostly about restricting access to whole directory trees, there is less need for wildcards there, and I'm not sure you can. Consult the Wikipedia article I linked to for details.

Comment: It should be noted that only using a robots.txt will get a google search console Coverage issue for anyone who is using search console.

Answer (score 0):

Typicall you can identify them by the user agent string. You can find a list here, can't say it's perferct, but it's a good base to extend: [PHP/MySQL - an array filter for bots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101165/php-mysql-an-array-filter-for-bots/)

Robots.txt is another way, [more about it here](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html)