# How to track relevant views using php

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I would like to track all views to a page using php and mysql. I will be tracking the number of times a person viewed the page and the ip address along with the current date. However is there a way to make sure your tracking actual users rather than bots/spiders?

Comment: i would use Google Analytics or an Apache log analyser like awstats. it would take you months of work to come to close to either of those options.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101165/php-mysql-an-array-filter-for-bots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options that I see:

1. Create a "hidden" link on your home page to a [honey pot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29).  Any one who hits the honey pot page should be considered a bot and not included in your stats

2: Not a fool proof way, but you could compare the browser's [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string to a white list of known web browsers.  This string can be spoofed so its not the most reliable.

Personally, I'd go with the first option.

For the honey pot:

on your home page I'd add something like this:

```
<a href="totallyNotATrap.php" style="Display:none">ReallyNotATrap</a>
```

and on the honey pot page itself something like this:

```
$BotIp=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//DB connection 
Insert into BlackList($BotIp,$Date,$otherDataYouCareAboutLogging);
//close DB Connection
```

Then for your stats code simply compare every user's Ip to the BlackList table.  If the user isn't on it, record the stats.

**EDIT**

As pointed out below, googlebot can get tricked by this.  If this is something that matters to you (if your just filtering for your own stats and not filtering content it shouldn't matter), include your honeypot page in your Robots.txt.  Google will read the text file and avoid the trap.  Other nasty bots will fall into it.  Since google will avoid our trap, I would also use option 2 and filter out Google's User Agent String from the stats.

Comment: Good point.  I'll include a robots.txt.  Google bot will follow that

Comment: OK, I understand your solution now. Interesting concept.

Comment: We've used something like this at my job.  So far its worked fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of real users should be basically the same number as the number of real users - bots.  If you want to you can check the User Agent which will tell you who is browsing the site.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out my tracking script, it's pretty simple to implement and bots and spiders will come up as a bunk browser so it's easy to weed them out. I use this on all my company's sites for analytics. There's one caveat though, if you use this for keyword tracking you may be disappointed real soon because Google is starting to [change the structure of their query strings](http://blog.performics.com/search/2011/10/how-should-search-marketers-respond-to-google-encrypted-search.html) for logged in users.

https://github.com/k4t434sis/tracking.php